# Programmatic configuration of error pages in Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

Servlet 3.0 allows for programmatic configuration of servlets, filters and listeners.
But what about error pages?

I can't see that there's any methods for doing that in `ServletContext`.

It would be nice to be able to completely abolish the `web.xml`.

Comment: There are indeed none. Just post a feature request against the [servlet spec](http://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC) if you think that it's mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical way one can programmatically add such a definition.